# Laravel Sanctum + Nuxt3 unauthenticated

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, laravel-10, nuxt3, laravel-sanctum

I believe that I'm completely lost of reading n articles & documentations and not sure what is the right way of using Sanctum. Just a heads up what I'm trying to reach/create before talking more about the issue. I want to build an application which will communicate only via API, basically via tokens. For that my back-end will be created with Laravel and front-end with Nuxt3. I think that most of my Laravel setup is correct, but the whole workflow is incorrect, the issue is now that after log in from Nuxt application I successfully receive user data and token. However, when I'm trying to enter protected endpoint with auth:sanctum - I receive 401 (Unauthorized). However, if I manually attach the Bearer token to request - everything is fine and that makes sense, but! I read somewhere that if I use in request withCredentials: true, it will manually attach the token to headers as a Authorization Bearer. Also, question came to my head - would it be really bad if save the token in localStorage?

Here's the Laravel part, which returns the token from log in:

```
 $token = Auth::user()->createToken('basic-app-token')->plainTextToken;

 $cookie = cookie('auth_token', $token, 30, null, null, false, true, false, 'Strict');

 return $this->successfullRequest($response, $message,200)->withCookie($cookie);
```

Maybe there is no point of attaching my own cookie? And Laravel from /sanctum/csrf-cookie will recognise the user and authorise it?

User successfully logs in and receives token:

```
    await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/sanctum/csrf-cookie', {
        withCredentials: true
    });


    const {data: {data: {user, token}}} = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/v1/auth/login', userData, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        withCredentials: true,
    });
```

The very next request to protected route looks like this:

```
   const request = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/v1/company', {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
        },
        withCredentials: true
    });

    console.log(request); // Returns 401
```

Answer (score 0):

On the backend side you should find the user in the database and create a token for them, then return them to the frontend.

```php
public function signIn(Request $request): JsonResponse
{
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|string'
    ]);

    $user = User::query()->where('email', $request->get('email'))->first();

    if (!$user || !Hash::check($request->get('password'), $user->password)) {
        throw new AuthorizationException(
            'The provided credentials are incorrect.',
            401
        );
    }

    return response()->json(['token' => $user->createToken(config('app.name'))->plainTextToken]);
}
```

on the front end you should store the token either in localStorage or in Cookie (this is the priority), but for the sake of simplicity, you can put it in localstorage. And then add `Bearer + token` to each `axios` request.

```js
const base = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_URL,
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('user-token') || ''}`
    },
    responseType: 'json', // default
    responseEncoding: 'utf8', // default
});
base.defaults.withCredentials = true;

 api.post('/auth/login', {email: this.email, password: this.password})
    .then(response => response.data)
    .then(response => {
       localStorage.setItem('user-token', response.token);
    })

 api.get('/api/v1/company').then(response => console.log(response.data));
```

*If you want to use Cookie then you need withCredentials, in case of localStorage you don't need to think about it.*

*Sanctum Guard* will take the token itself and check if it exists in the database. You can see this in `vendor/laravel/sanctum/src/Guard.php`

```php
public function __invoke(Request $request)

....


if ($token = $request->bearerToken()) {
    $model = Sanctum::$personalAccessTokenModel;

    $accessToken = $model::findToken($token);

    if (! $this->isValidAccessToken($accessToken) ||
        ! $this->supportsTokens($accessToken->tokenable)) {
        return;
    }

    if (method_exists($accessToken->getConnection(), 'hasModifiedRecords') &&
        method_exists($accessToken->getConnection(), 'setRecordModificationState')) {
        tap($accessToken->getConnection()->hasModifiedRecords(), function ($hasModifiedRecords) use ($accessToken) {
            $accessToken->forceFill(['last_used_at' => now()])->save();

            $accessToken->getConnection()->setRecordModificationState($hasModifiedRecords);
        });
    } else {
        $accessToken->forceFill(['last_used_at' => now()])->save();
    }

    return $accessToken->tokenable->withAccessToken(
        $accessToken
    );
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for quick response. I'm sending on login the token as httpOnly cookie to client:

$cookie = cookie('auth_token', $token, 30, null, null, false, true, false, 'Lax');

return $this->successfullRequest($response, $message,200)->withCookie($cookie)

Everything goes well with log in, receiving successfully the token. Then I navigate to other page where I click on random button to receive data, I receive Internal error, even the route exists. Also using useFetch, where I set credentials: 'include'

Comment: Also, my Sanctum Guard looks little bit different than you provided. Any ideas what can cause that?

Comment: Also, in personal_access_tokens table I'm able to see the new tokens which are issued by Laravel. If I manually add Authorization headers - everything is fine

Comment: In your example, I didn't see you set the `Authorization: Bearer {token}` header.

To understand the reason you can put `dd($request->bearerToken())` in `vendor/laravel/sanctum/src/Guard.php` and make sure that there is a token there, which is in the database.

Comment: You can omit `$cookie = cookie('auth_token', $token, 30, null, null, false, true, false, 'Lax');.` Simply set the `auth_token` to cookie after front-end login using [js-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-cookie). `withCredentials` option will ensure the token is passed to the backend, and the backend will send it back anyway.  

Another view may come from the version of Sanctum you are using

Comment: Not sure why everything started working after setting the  SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:3000 with the port, but when I have a XSRF-TOKEN and laravel_sessions as a cookies, I don't need to pass the token from backend as a httpOnly cookie? Or still need? Because cleared cache, tried to pass without token as cookie and still worked? Feeling completely lost :D

Comment: you have `EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful` enabled inside there is a check on `referer` that it is included in the allowed list of domains. That's why it didn't pass the check. This can be checked in `app/Http/Kernel.php` in the `api` block.

Comment: `api` works without sessions, so you only need to pass in the `Authorization: Bearer token` header. In the `config/sanctum.php` file there is a `middleware.verify_csrf_token` block, it answers whether you need to verify `csrf` or not.

Comment: Sorry for asking a lot, feeling dumb :) .. My Nuxt app communicates via API only, you mentioned that api works without sessions - makes sense. But does it mean that if I enable EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful - it won't require any Authorization headers for my routes even they are protected with auth:sanctum?

Comment: No, those routes secured via `auth:sanctum` will always require an `Authorization` header with a token. `EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful` - middleware is responsible for ensuring that incoming requests can authenticate using cookies, i.e. it works with your cookies and validates the csrf token if needed

Comment: I think it makes sense now, thank you Denis, appreciate your help! Maybe you have any project example, just to have for a reference?

Comment: I described to you above (code) a working example or do you want to see the full backend and frontend?

Comment: Would be really nice to see the full backend and frontend, because still have some doubts about sending the headers :)

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed.. I thought I had the right .env file for SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS... It was `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost`, had to have the port of my SPA, for the current case:  `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:3000`